# post to tumblr using iphone SDK and "/api/write "

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How to authenticate and then post text to tumblr from the iphone SDK for tumblr 
Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function For post to tumblr Hope this will help you :)

```
- (IBAction)postToTumblr1
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    BOOL b = [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailtext.text];


    if (b==NO) 
    {
        UIAlertView *messageBox = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@" " message:@"Invalid Email ID" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [messageBox show];
        [messageBox release];
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/api/write"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        // tell the server to expect 8-bit encoded content as we're sending UTF-8 data, and UTF-8 is an 8-bit encoding
        [request addValue:@"8bit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];

        //set the content-type header to multipart MIME
        [request addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", [NSString MIMEBoundary]] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        //create a dictionary for all the fields you want to send in the POST request
        NSDictionary* postData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 emailtext.text, @"email",
                                 password.text, @"password",
                                 @"regular", @"type",
                                 @"The Real Compatibility Tester", @"title",
                                 postText, @"body",
                                 nil];

        //set the body of the POST request to the multipart MIME encoded dictionary
        [request setHTTPBody: [[NSString multipartMIMEStringWithDictionary: postData] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSLog(@"Tumblr Login:%@\nTumblr ", emailtext.text);

        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [request release];

        yes = 1;

        if(1)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Tumblr Post" message:@"Post successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
        else 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Tumblr Post" message:@"Post not  successfully done" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/file/q8Z5jY8k/TumblrLoginViewController.html

Comment: check out my both link http://www.4shared.com/file/zMbGJvwb/TumblrLoginViewController.html

Comment: Worst Code Example I have ever seen....

Comment: i am using your suggested code for tumblr text and image post(Stack overflow). all thing is going well but when I post any thing we are getting Authentication fail as response. can you guide me why this error occurring and what i have to use in place of email and password, I am using actual email/password like hitaishin.ios@gmail.com/hitaihinifotech. one more thing, in the setting of tumblr account I found one option for generating email for posting text or photo. I also use such email ("3yqo4ahfjhcds@tumblr.com")and password is hitaishininfotech but i am getting same response . Please help.

Comment: @RamS : download https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK

Comment: @M.B I have download this sdk, there is problem. Actually i want to post on button click, in this example shows that they open action sheet..... , one more thing this demo application is not running having lots of bugs. Can you please give me your contact no. or skype id. actually i am unable to submit this app due to tumblr is not supporting, and client is not considering, this is  very crucial time for me.... please guide me .. how to implement tumblr

Answer (score 2):

****@charanjit i have write a code for that by which u can post text on tumbler try this code:-

```
@interface NSString (MIMEAdditions)
+ (NSString*)MIMEBoundary;
+ (NSString*)multipartMIMEStringWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict;
@end

@implementation NSString (MIMEAdditions)

//this returns a unique boundary which is used in constructing the multipart MIME body of the POST request
+ (NSString*)MIMEBoundary
{
    static NSString* MIMEBoundary = nil;

    if(!MIMEBoundary)
        MIMEBoundary = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"----_=TheRealTester%@_=_----",[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]];

    return MIMEBoundary;
}

//this create a correctly structured multipart MIME body for the POST request from a dictionary
+ (NSString*)multipartMIMEStringWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict 
{
    NSMutableString* result = [NSMutableString string];

    for (NSString* key in dict)
    {
        [result appendFormat:@"--%@\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\n\n%@\n",[NSString MIMEBoundary],key,[dict objectForKey:key]];
    }

    [result appendFormat:@"\n--%@--\n",[NSString MIMEBoundary]];
    return result;
}

@end
```

**above code for write in .m file before implementation .
after that write this code..

```
- (IBAction)postToTumblr1
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    BOOL b = [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailtext.text];

    if (b==NO) {        
        UIAlertView *messageBox = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@" " message:@"Invalid Email ID" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [messageBox show];
        [messageBox release];  
    }
    else {
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/api/write"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        //tell the server to expect 8-bit encoded content as we're sending UTF-8 data, and UTF-8 is an 8-bit encoding
        [request addValue:@"8bit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];

        //set the content-type header to multipart MIME
        [request addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",[NSString MIMEBoundary]] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        //create a dictionary for all the fields you want to send in the POST request
        NSDictionary* postData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 emailtext.text, @"email",
                                 password.text, @"password",
                                 @"regular", @"type",
                                 @"The Real Compatibility Tester", @"title",
                                 postText, @"body",
                                 nil];

        //set the body of the POST request to the multipart MIME encoded dictionary
        [request setHTTPBody: [[NSString multipartMIMEStringWithDictionary: postData] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSLog(@"Tumblr Login:%@\nTumblr ", emailtext.text);

        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [request release];

        yes=1;

        if(1) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Tumblr Post" message:@"Post successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
        else 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Tumblr Post" message:@"Post not  successfully done" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];
            [alert release]; 
        }
    }
 }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"cancel");
    }
}
```

Comment: [request setHTTPBody:(NSData*)]
and we are passing NSString so it is giving me exception

Comment: I am using above code but i got response Authentication fail. i am using 3yqo4ahfjhcds@tumblr.com email and password which is log in for tubmlr website. hitaishininfotech. please help any one why i am getting Authentication fail from response.